# Ignore HTTP Proxy error

Tags: inno-setup, fiddler

In my setup i send HTTP request to a server in order to see those requests on fiddler i add the following code - `WinHttpReq.SetProxy(2, '127.0.0.1:8888');`

Unfortunately, if fiddle isn't turned on I get error message as follows- [image]

Is it possible to ignore that message?

Comment: thanks Tlama, but isn't there a much specific way to solve this, lets say like, ignore error, or ignore specific error, you see i send 16 different HTTP requests in my inno each request has this `WinHttpReq.SetProxy(2, '127.0.0.1:8888');` for it, i dont want to write 16 times `try...except`

Comment: Hi Tlama, I tries `try..except` this way:

`[Setup]
AppName=Test
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\test

[Code]
var
WinHttpReq: Variant;
function ShowInFiddler(Param: String): String;
begin
try
WinHttpReq.SetProxy(2, '127.0.0.1:8888');
except 
MsgBox('Hello.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
end;

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
WinHttpReq := CreateOleObject('WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1');
WinHttpReq.Open('GET', 'http://publishers-xxxx.databssint.com/', false);
ShowInFiddler (''); 
WinHttpReq.Send();
end;`

but it doesn't work, can anybody help?

Comment: Oh, I assumed that you wrapped your function calls by `OleCheck` (which I've seen in some example). Well, without it is such usage of `try..except` block pointless. Each WinHTTP function returns an `HRESULT` value which you should check for `S_OK` value and if it differs from this value, something has failed (what exactly failed you can get from the lower 16 bits of that value or by `DLLGetLastError` Inno Setup function). [btw. I've cleaned up the *workspace* from my comments]

Comment: I think i'll ask this Q in the comment above in new Q?
what do you thing Tlama?

Comment: Yes, I think it will be better to open a new thread for that.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be to not set the proxy when Fiddler isn't running.

You haven't told us anything about your environment that would enable anyone to help you further.

Comment: this is what i do today and it's not a good approach,
the QA team that check the setup want to see the HTTP requests on fiddle, so I add the proxy,after they approve the setup i must remove the proxy, so i compile a new setup, ans so i upload a non approved setup to prod.

Comment: @ElramV, what about a setup command line parameter for specifying proxy ? Your QA team would run the setup with a known command line parameter which end users wouldn't know.