# try and except bug in inno setup

Tags: inno-setup

In my code I wish to send http request and present it in fiddler - `WinHttpReq.SetProxy(2, '127.0.0.1:8888');` if fiddle is up,

if fiddler is down dost esnd it to fiddler  , I tried `try..except` this way:

```
[Setup] AppName=Test AppVersion=1.5 DefaultDirName={pf}\test 

[Code] 
var 
WinHttpReq: Variant; 
function ShowInFiddler(Param: String): String;
begin 
try
 WinHttpReq.SetProxy(2, '127.0.0.1:8888'); 
except  MsgBox('Hello.', mbInformation, MB_OK); 
end;
 end;  
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean; 
begin 
WinHttpReq := CreateOleObject('WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1'); 
WinHttpReq.Open('GET', 'http://publishers-xxxx.databssint.com/', false); 
ShowInFiddler ('');  
WinHttpReq.Send(); end;
```

but the exception doesn't work, can anybody help?

Comment: Why not just make sure that the `SetProxy` call is ONLY in your testing version? That way you see it in your testing but any version you send out won't have a needless attempt to connect to a local proxy.

Comment: this is what we do today, it's not the best practice since ideal is that QA will approve the installer we'll upload to prod, any chance you know why is my `try and except` doesn't work here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a bug in Inno Setup, because the SetProxy function doesn't check if the proxy is availible. The function will raise an exception if you call it with wrong parameters.
So if your proxy is down you should catch the exception of the Send function and e.g. use the default proxy settings to [continue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25708042/ignore-http-proxy-error).

For example:

```
var 
  WinHttpReq: Variant;

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin 
  WinHttpReq := CreateOleObject('WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1'); 
  WinHttpReq.Open('GET', 'http://publishers-xxxx.databssint.com/', false);
  WinHttpReq.SetProxy(2, '127.0.0.1:8888');
  try
    // first try connecting via given proxy
    WinHttpReq.Send();
  except
    // proxy failed, use default settings
    WinHttpReq.SetProxy(0);
    try
      WinHttpReq.Send();
      Result := true;
    except
      // conncetion failed, handle error here
      ShowExceptionMessage();
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Keep in mind, that the *debugger* will paused by default on an exception (proxy is down). This will not happen in runtime.
Hope it helps.

Comment: that done it! 10x "anotheruser" MY QA team says Hooray!